# How to use a set as a key in a (v)map?

Tags: nftables

For example, one can:

```
ip saddr vmap { 192.168.1.2: goto chain_a, 192.168.1.6: goto chain_b }
```

but apparently not:

```
ip saddr vmap { { 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.4 }: goto chain_a,
                { 192.168.1.6, 192.168.1.8 }: goto chain_b }
```

I know one can:

```
ip saddr vmap { 192.168.1.2: goto chain_a, 192.168.1.4: goto chain_a,
                192.168.1.6: goto chain_b, 192.168.1.8: goto chain_b }
```

Or even just:

```
ip saddr { 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.4 } goto chain_a
ip saddr { 192.168.1.6, 192.168.1.8 } goto chain_b
```

But I'm just curious whether there's a way to use a set (or anything similar) as a key in a (v)map.

Comment: Likewise or related ipset's `list:set` type, to have multiple interchangeable sets checked with a single rule, has no equivalent (yet?) in nftables.

Answer (score 1):

In [nftables 1.0.0](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg60370.html) (released Aug 2021), you can do this:

**Expand variable containing set into multiple mappings**

```
define interfaces = { eth0, eth1 }

 table ip x {
       chain y {
               type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
               iifname vmap { lo : accept, $interfaces : drop }
       }
}
# nft -f x.nft
# nft list ruleset
table ip x {
      chain y {
               type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
               iifname vmap { "lo" : accept, "eth0" : drop, "eth1" : drop }
       }
}
```

I don't know if using a set that is not within a variable works as well, but now it may, because each new version of `nftables` increases possibilities.